# Picking up the coordinates inside this polygon draw

Tags: leaflet, javascript, point-in-polygon, leaflet-plugins, leaflet-geoman

I already have a geojson being consulted and that is plotting these black dots. And then I inserted the leaflet-geoman plugin to give users the freedom to create polygons on the map. Basically draw something there.

[image]

For example: Draw a polygon to get only the information inside that polygon.

When using the tool to draw a polygon on the map I wanted to get which black dot is inside the drawing

[image]

in short: I have 4 points within my polygon drawing (which does not come from a geojson, the person draws) and I want to get the information from those points that are within that drawn polygon. Each black dot in this one has an id, and I want to know what points are within the space that the person drew.

My geoman-Leaflet code:

```js
      map.pm.addControls({
        position: 'topright',
        // drawCircle: false,
        drawMarker: false,
        drawCircleMarker: false,
        drawRectangle: false,
        cutPolygon: false,
        editPolygon: false,
      });
```

My black dots on the map code:

```js
  wellheads.forEach(function (d) {
        d.LatLng = new L.latLng(d.latitude, d.longitude);
      });

  const groupWells = g
        .selectAll('g')
        .data(wellheads)
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('pointer-events', 'visible');

      const points = groupWells
        .append('circle')
        .attr('class', d => {
          if (wellState.selectedWell.guid === d.wellboreGUID) {
            return 'redW';
          } else {
            return 'blackW';
          }
        })
        .attr('id', d => `id-${d.wellboreGUID}`)
        .attr('r', d => {
          if (wellState.selectedWell.guid === d.wellboreGUID) {
            return 1.7;
          } else {
            return 1.0;
          }
        })
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Please edit your question and part of the code where/when circle is created and you would like to get info about contained points.

Comment: @TomazicM I think she creates the circle directly as svg path and not as `L.Circle`, like that how it is in the question. But I'm also not sure. And can you please create the tag [leaflet-geoman], because this is not leaflet-draw. I would do it by myself but I have not enough reputation on GIS SE

Comment: @FalkeDesign Whatever kind of circle it is, at the time of creation it has known center and radius, and that's what is needed to get points within radius. As far as new tag is concerned, I don't have enough privilege to create it.

Comment: guys, i creat the circle just with the geoman-leaflet, and in the question has the cod. from the moment I add the draw toolbar, I can draw any polygon on the map.

i put the code referent from de dots. My dots i made with append circle in another function.

I want from the moment I draw a polygon with the geoman-leaflet I can get the ID of each black dot

Comment: @TomazicM i cannot find the leaflet-geoman, thats why i did not put.

Comment: rI'm not familiar with the `geoman-leaflet` plugin, but I'm sure there exists event processing function/callback, which is/can be called at the time when circle draw is finished and where center coordinate and radius is available. Please edit your question and add that part of the code. I'm also not familiar with `react`, so maybe I'm asking altogether wrong things.

Answer (score 2):

This could be achieved with [turf.js' booleanWithin](https://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanWithin), by testing each point against the created polygon.

For example you can a listener for when the drawing is complete:

```
map.on('pm:create', (e) => {  
  feature = e.layer.toGeoJSON();
  wellheads.forEach(function (d) {
        d.within = turf.booleanWithin(turf.point([d.longitude, d.latitude]), feature );
      });
});
```

This is a basic way to test this, I would recommend using `L.marker` or `L.circle` on your maps instead of manually drawing svg paths on the canvas.

Comment: GeoJSON does not have circle geometry. Does `leaflet-geoman` plugin create some approximate polygon?

Comment: It does, but the question wasn't specific to circles, but to a drawn polygon, at least when I answered it. Whatever polygon `leaflet-geoman` draws should work with turf since it accepts either turf.js geometry or a GeoJSON feature

Comment: i cannot use l.circle or l.marker, i need just draw a polygon in the map. this polygon or circle is not a ready geojson. is the person who can draw from the geoman-leaflet drawing tool

Comment: @DrorBogin As I wrote, GeoJSON standard doesn't have circle geometry, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON#Geometries. As far as question goes, there is image of circle and then statement: "I want to know what is the id of the pins that are within that radius."

Comment: @TomazicM as I stated, when I answered the question it was "I was wondering if there is a possibility that I can get the id's of these black dots but that are inside my polygon?". since `leaflet-geoman` supports multiple polygon types, my answer is true for all of them, whether circular or not.

Comment: @RayssaRocha I meant use leaflet built in classes instead of the second part of the code, the one where you add the points to the map.

Comment: i made a update on question, I think you were not understanding the question

Comment: @RayssaRocha You just want to output the id's? thats just as easy, look throug my answer, it tests all your points whenever a new polygon is added.

Comment: @DrorBogin but my black dots are geojson and are already plotted on the map, regardless of draw.

Comment: My code was referring to the way you drew your black dots.